# map out multiple columns from an RDD

Tags: pyspark

I want to map out two different columns from an RDD in other to carry out further evaluation on it but could not, the code below mapped out only column 8

DefenseList = noHeader.map(lambda x: x.split(",")[7])

DefenseList.collect()

and the code below mapped out from columns 2-8

DefenseList = noHeader.map(lambda x: x.split(",")[1:7])

DefenseList.collect()

but i am trying to get only columns 2 and 8,your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can first do the split and then use a second map to extract the specific elements.

here's an example

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['this,is,a,line,from,txt,file']). \
    map(lambda r: r.split(',')). \
    map(lambda r: [r[1], r[5]]). \
    collect()

# [['is', 'txt']]
```